# Why it's create localhost:5000 CLOSE_WAIT Node?

Tags: node.js

my server started with PORT 5000, and sometimes it show next error

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
```

When I Check port 5000, I see what port :5000 use for Chrome. They pass away after time( 1 min ) but, it's create more problems, i don't check code with terminal, because after error not showing console.log?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that chrome is launched by some development tool. Because System apps can not take port number more that 1024. So you need to check if your IDE is launching it and then check how to change the port or you can follow [this](https://gist.github.com/mikeal/1840641) link to auto increment the port if given port is not available.

```
var portrange = 45032

function getPort (cb) {
  var port = portrange
  portrange += 1

  var server = net.createServer()
  server.listen(port, function (err) {
    server.once('close', function () {
      cb(port)
    })
    server.close()
  })
  server.on('error', function (err) {
    getPort(cb)
  })
}
```

Code from link